# Can SonarQube detect unused public static objects in java

Tags: java, sonarqube

We have a LARGE legacy java application that has it's own string localization system.
One part of this is that we have a bunch of interfaces with entries like:

```
static final VocabTxt BACK = new VocabTxt("BACK");
```

Those interfaces are all implemented by a central class for ease of use.
I know that there are a bunch of these that are no longer in use.
Is there some rule I can use in SonarQube to find the not referenced ones?

Comment: What if they are referenced from client code outside of your codebase?

Comment: If we this was a library, that would be a concern.  In this case, it's all within the same app, and we are only worried about references from the app.

Comment: This can be done by your IDE easily. If you use IntelliJ IDEA all unused statics should be displayed greyed out.

Comment: I use Eclipse, and not IntelliJ.
Have you tested IntelliJ with PUBLIC static finals that aren't used?
It's easy to detect private ones.

Answer (score 1):

Finding those unused entities within a project requires cross-file analysis, which the SonarJava analyzer doesn't do yet (altho work in that area is ongoing).